# Zingaya possible call from web page Likewise By using Nexmo/Twilio (possible/not possible) to call click that button from web page?

Tags: php, twilio, vonage

Anybody help me for answer the following Questions.

Zingaya enables voice calls through any computer, right from a webpage. No download or phone is required. Zingaya offers this seamless voice calling capability to website operators – whether it’s a huge e-commerce enterprise or your personal blog. Simply embed a “Call” button into your website. Visitors can click that button and the call is immediately forwarded to your landline, mobile phone, Skype account, or other computer. All you need is a website; all your visitors need is a browser and microphone. It’s that easy.

https://zingaya.com/
https://api.zingaya.com/ZingayaAPI2/Reference.pdf

Likewise, By Using Nexmo/Twilio make a call from web page to particular mobile number is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with Nexmo. We wrote [a blog post about this back in 2018](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2018/08/21/phone-call-web-browser-nexmo-in-app-voice-vue-js-dr). It still provides a good example of the code you would need to implement to make this possible.

However things have changed a little since then and it is now possible to build a click to call button using the Nexmo JavaScript Client SDK.

All the code and all the steps to go through to build it are in the [Client SDK Documentation](https://developer.nexmo.com/client-sdk/in-app-voice/getting-started/make-phone-call)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely possible with Twilio using a few different approaches.

1. Call across the public telephone network (PSTN) - connecting both via their regular phone.
2. Connecting the two parties and calls using VoIP (using WebRTC)
3. A combination of both approaches for each call leg

You can also layer on a lot of additional call routing logic and/or mix channels based on your requirements (voice and SMS for example).

[Build Click-to-Call into your Web Application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/click-to-call)

[Twilio Client Javascript Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart)